# Partial integration problem $ \int (\arcsin x) (1-x^2)^{-3/2}dx\:$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

The problem is:

$$ \int \frac{\arcsin \left(x\right)}{\sqrt{\left(1-x^2\right)^3}}dx\:$$

My book suggests to use substitution arcsin(x) = z, if I do that I am left with:

$$ \int \:\frac{zdz}{1-x^2} $$

I can't really do partial integration on that, so what substitution should I actually use, to be able to proceed?

Comment: If $\arcsin(x) = z$, then $x = \sin(z)$. If you finish the substitution, the denominator will be $1-\sin^2(z)$ and that is a trig identity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that you are left with the denominator $1 - x^2$. Now we need to find an expression for $x$ in the denominator in terms of $z$, so we can integrate with respect to $z$. That would be $\sin(\arcsin x) = \sin z \iff x = \sin z$.

So you have the integral $$\int \frac{z\,dz}{1- \sin^2 z} = \int \frac{z\,dz}{\cos^2 z} = \int z\sec^2 z\,dz$$

Do integration by parts: $u = z \implies du = dz,\;\;dv = \sec^2 z \,dz \implies v = \tan z$

Comment: thanks that's it, didn't really know you could do that. Also someone edited it to 1-z^2 it was x^2

Comment: Yes, I saw the mistaken edit, and your original post. I corrected the edit you did not make.

Comment: I now understand, thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome!